# Perl: Compare two hashes, remove keys from one

Tags: perl

What I am attempting to do:

Store files and their md5 hash values into a hash, changing the hash when files are added or deleted.

So far I am able to store the md5 hashes and update the hash when files are added.
However I am not sure how to delete the keys for files that are removed

My Approach right now is to:

## turn array into a hash to compare

```
my %files = map { $_ => 1 } @files;
```

## check to see if they are the same

```
if (%files ~~  %hash).. same.. else... different
```

I'm not sure how to implement this further.. here is my thinking:

## Delete the key in the hash that no longer has a file(pseudo code)

```
Where exists $hash{$_} && !exists $files{$_} delete $hash{$_}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create hashes to compare lists.  Have a look at [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aCompare).  In particular, the get_unique() and get_complement() methods will identify items which only appear in one of your two lists.

Comment: There is no XS in `List::Compare`. I doubt it's any faster, looking at the code it doesn't look to impressive either.

Comment: I used List::Compare::Functional qw( get_complement ); Which solved my problem. I made an array of the keys, and then compared the two arrays. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just loop over one, and check if exists and delete...

```
foreach my $k ( keys %file ) {
  delete $hash{$k} if exists $hash{$k};
}
```

Also, because of internals when using an hash for this purpose you're better off assigning `undef` than `1` to it. Reasons withheld for simplicity.

```
my %files = map { $_ => undef } @files;
```

I'm not sure if the conditional makes it faster or slower -- it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm curious about the use of undef instead of 1 in hashes. Do you mind adding an appendix on that?

Comment: @stevenl `undef` in perl is stored as `SV_UNDEF` which is just a pointer to `NULL(0x0)`, rather than an `IV` which has overhead like flags pertaining to what it is (context), and how to render it.